# Continue execution without throw the exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I running a procedure in while loop and when there is an exception its exiting the procedure.
But I want the procedure should continue executing other entity in while loop and should exit the procedure instead it would log error in the table. So that we can the table once the procedure completed the execution.
Please let me know if you any solution.

```
 CREATE PROC [DYNAMIC_PROC_MAIN]  AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

/* Variable Declaration */
DECLARE @CheckError INT = 0;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(4000); 
DECLARE @Current_date datetime
DECLARE @VMaxlevel bigint    
DECLARE @RowCount bigint  

DECLARE @Vraa_name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Vformula VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Vlevel INT
--DECLARE @Vmonth VARCHAR(50) = '202306'

DECLARE @InputValue varchar(1000)
DECLARE @LastRefreshDate datetime

DECLARE @number_of_rows int 
DECLARE @row_count INT

DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 1

DECLARE @CounterList INT
SET @CounterList = 1

DECLARE @Vtemp VARCHAR(4000)

SET @VMaxlevel = 
    (select max(level_id)
FROM Level_t)

WHILE (@Counter <= @VMaxlevel )


BEGIN TRY
        --Print(@VMaxlevel)
        Set @InputValue = @MonthValue

    SELECT @Current_date=GETUTCDATE()
    SELECT @LastRefreshDate=GETUTCDATE()
    
    
        --Print(@Counter)
      
        SET @RowCount = 
    (SELECT count(distinct lt.ID) FROM Level_t2 lt
WHERE lt.level=@counter)
         
        WHILE (@CounterList <= @RowCount )
     BEGIN
        

     /* Begin creation a temp table to store recrods in runtime */
            BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#kpi_maintmptbl') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
            --print 'Hello'
            DROP TABLE #kpi_maintmptbl
            END
            --GO
            create table #kpi_maintmptbl
            with (
            DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
            ,HEAP
            )
            AS (select distinct lt.name FROM Level_t3 lt
            where lt.level=@CounterList)
            

            END

            /* End creation a temp table to store recrods in runtime */

            DECLARE @recordCount int = (SELECT COUNT(1) from #kpi_maintmptbl)
            DECLARE @counter1 int = 1
            DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
            WHILE @counter1 <= @recordCount 

            BEGIN

                  SET @name = (SELECT [name]
                  FROM(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY                     [raa_name]) AS RN
                  FROM #kpi_maintmptbl) as T
                  WHERE RN = @counter1)
                 

                              
                  PRINT @name
                  PRINT @Vlevel
                  Print @counter1

                
                EXEC DYNAMIC_PROC  @name
                 
                 
                  SET @counter1 = @counter1 + 1

             END
     SET @CounterList = @CounterList +1
    END
--SET @Counter = @Counter +1


END TRY

Begin Catch

    DECLARE
        @ErrorSeverity INT,
        @ErrorState INT;
                

            SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),          
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),          
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
            RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    
        
        SELECT @Current_date=GETUTCDATE()
       

        SET @CheckError = ERROR_NUMBER()
        SET @ErrorMessage = concat(@name,'-',ERROR_MESSAGE())
        SELECT @Current_date=GETUTCDATE()

       INSERT INTO dl_config.CL_Error_Log 
       VALUES('DYNAMIC_PROC_MAIN',@CheckError,@ErrorMessage,@Current_date,NULL);

   --THROW

   End Catch

SET @Counter = @Counter +1      

    End
    
GO
```

Comment: If you don't want to exit due to an error, don't throw the error in the `CATCH` block. Instead just log it, and also increment your counter outside of the try/catch block. Having a try/catch block that catches an error without doing anything other than throwing it is pretty pointless anyway.

Comment: What exactly is this procedure doing that it needs to run in a loop?

Comment: @Charlieface This loop automating the execution. This is needed to ease the manual intervention.

Comment: Yes what I'm saying is: why does it need to be a loop? You almost never need a loop in SQL, so if you show what the procedure is *actually* doing we can probably improve it.

Comment: @GarethD I have tried it in the given way. But in case of exception the loop is kept executing. means going in infinite loop.

Comment: Have you moved `SET @Counter = @Counter +1` outside of the `TRY`? As it stands you are executing the procedure first, if that fails you'll never increment the counter and you'll end up in an infinite loop. In a [simple example I have created](https://dbfiddle.uk/u9rRy1Kg) the loop continues as expected regardless of error.

Comment: @GarethD Yes i did that. Still there is issue. Yes the called procedure have the exception in it. So in that case how that will be happened? Can you please let me know?

Comment: @GarethD EXEC DYNAMIC_PROC this has dynamic queries and it fails for some ID. There are thousand ids and there will be exception in executing the dynamic query. So how that can be skipped if there is an exception?

Comment: I've already given an example of how to do that. Can you post the actual code you have tried, including the changes to move where you increment, and no longer throw the error? Trying to debug code I can't see is proving quite tricky....

Comment: @GarethD Have pasted my code. Please take a look and it and suggest.

Comment: Where have you pasted the code? The code in the question hasn't changed since yesterday, and the issues with that code have already been pointed out.

Comment: @GarethD Unable to add the code. Showing context missing,

Comment: @GarethD Now I did the change. Please check the code.

Comment: @GarethD Thank you. Begin /End is missing. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your procedure to continue on error, you shouldn't throw after you catch it (or use `raiseerror`). Instead, you can use a table, a table variable or a temporary table to store error information and continue the loop.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @Errors as Table
(
    Severity int,
    State int,
    Message nvarchar(4000)
);

WHILE (@Counter <= @VMaxlevel )
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC DYNAMIC_PROC
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO @Errors(Severity, State, Message)
    VALUES(ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_MESSAGE());
END CATCH
-- This will ensure the counter will be raised even in case of an error
SET @Counter = @Counter +1
END
```

As a side note - loops are usually the wrong tool to use in SQL, so if it possible to avoid the loop altogether, it would probably be a better thing to do.

Comment: @GarethD Thank you for your response. I will try and confirm.

Comment: @GarethD Loops are used for the automation actually. Is there any better way other than this? Can you please suggest?

Comment: I'm not GarethD, but without knowing the specifics its hard to tell if you can actually avoid looping or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have now moved the `SET` that increments the counter outside of the loop itself. You have this:

```
WHILE(@Counter <= @VMaxlevel)
BEGIN TRY
....
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
....
END CATCH

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
```

Since you aren't using `BEGIN/END` the `WHILE` is using your `BEGIN TRY/END CATCH` to determine the loop statement. You need an additional `BEGIN/END` in here, so you are incrementing the counter outside of the try/catch block,  but inside of the loop

```
WHILE(@Counter <= @VMaxlevel)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    ....
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    ....
    END CATCH

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END
```

Honestly though, I can barely make sense of what your code is trying to do, but I can't imagine any scenario where a loop within a loop within a loop is a good idea. It's hard to say exactly what the fix is without knowing what `DYNAMIC_PROC` does, but there is almost certainly a more efficient and more maintainable way of doing this.

If your nested BEGIN/END and loops get so complicated that even the author can't keep track of what is in which block, then it is probably time to rethink the approach....